# Filtering data in Pandas returns error 'method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as follows: 
I am going to filter rows where the counts value equals 1.

```
index      count
1           4
2           5
3           1
4           1
```

This is my code:

```
booleans =[]

for number in df1.count:
    if number ==1:
        booleans.append (True)
    else:
        booleans.append (False)
```

but it has this error:

```
'method' object is not iterable
```

I also tried this:

```
df[df.count==1]
```

but I had the following error:

```
KeyError: False
```

any suggestion?

Comment: What about `df[df['count'] == 1]`? DataFrames have a `.count()` method, which is one reason why I prefer accessing columns using brackets and quotes (`df['colname']`) instead of dot notation (`df.colname`).

Comment: This is the reason I never use the dot notation, it can be confusing for a reader and sometimes apparently for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the problem is with the this part `df1.count`. Actually, pandas is having a method `count()` which is used to count the no. of non-NA/null observations across the given axis.

And in your code it returns something like this,

```
<bound method DataFrame.count of   index count
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     1
3     4     1>
```

Instead of it, you can use `df[df['count']=='1']` to get what you were looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"index":['1','2','3','4'],
        "count":['4','5','1','1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
indexes = df[df['count']=='1']
print(indexes)
```

**Output**

```
     index count
   2     3     1
   3     4     1
```

Comment: This is bad advice, it leads to chained indexing and will eventually cause a SettingWithCopyWarning.

Comment: @cs95 Got you, sir I think it will not be a problem if i do something like df[df['count']=='1'] this ?

Answer (score 2):

[Count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html)  is also a method of `pandas` DataFrame.

When you do `df.count`, pandas understands you are calling the `count()` method, not fetching your column that happens to have the same name. Doing `df["count"]` would solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to do the following:

**Solution 1**

```
df1[df1["count"]=='1']
```

**Solution 2**
However, if you really do want to get a list of booleans you might want to use lambdas:

```
booleans = list(df1['count'].apply(lambda x:x=='1').values)
```

You can then use this list to get the result you want like so:

```
df1[booleans]
```

This is basically the same thing as solution 1.